# Containers will not align with one another. Changing width results in undesired outcomes

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new to HTML and CSS. I have a list that serves as a navigation bar for a website, which is inside the div "inner header." I was able to align the "nav" container (in teal) to the right edge of the "inner header" container, but I am struggling to do the same for the  items within nav (in red).

Containers Appearance  [image]

Essentially, I would like the text to align with the teal on the right side, but I noticed no matter what I do, the red will not expand. I've tried changing width to 100%, but that causes each word to separate into three rows (possible due to the display type?).

If I add width: 98px, it gets closer to my desired outcome, but it doesn't perfectly align with the teal.

Close to desired outcome [image]

Any advice is appreciated!

```css
.inner_header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #8ecae6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav a {
  height: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 98px;
}

.nav a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.nav a li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner_header">
  
    <div class="logo_container">
      <img src=".png">
      <img src=".jpeg">
    </div>

    <p>Text <br> Text</p>

    <ul class="nav">
      <a>
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a>
        <li>Data</li>
      </a>
      <a>
        <li>Tool</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand what you wanted, I'm just taking a guess here and tried to get the result closer to your screenshot and based on what you explained.

```css
.inner_header {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #8ecae6;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 70%;
  display: table;
  background-color: teal;
  text-align: right;
  padding:0;
}

.nav a {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0px 20px;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
}

.nav a:last-child {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.nav a li {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="inner_header">
  
    <div class="logo_container">
      <img src=".png">
      <img src=".jpeg">
    </div>

    <p>Text <br> Text</p>

    <ul class="nav">
      <a>
        <li>Home</li>
      </a>
      <a>
        <li>Data</li>
      </a>
      <a>
        <li>Tool</li>
      </a>
    </ul>
    
  </div>
</div>
```